# render controls in div at run time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rendering, innerhtml

i have atext from jquery method :

```
   <fieldset>
  <ul id="ContentPlaceHolder2_1g" class="profList column ui-sortable">
 <legend class="group">المجموعه 1</legend>
 <li id="ContentPlaceHolder2_8">محمود حسن ابراهيم عبد الصمد</li>
 /ul></fieldset>



<fieldset>
<ul id="ContentPlaceHolder2_2g" class="profList column ui-sortable">
<legend class="group">المجموعه 2</legend>
<li id="ContentPlaceHolder2_9">محمود فتحى ابراهيم عبد الصمد</li>
<li id="ContentPlaceHolder2_10">احمد محسن احمد على</li>
<li class="" style="" id="ContentPlaceHolder2_3">احمد درويش محمود عباس</li>
</ul>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<ul id="ContentPlaceHolder2_3g" class="profList column ui-sortable">
 <legend class="group">المجموعه 3</legend>
 <li id="ContentPlaceHolder2_11">محمد سيد محمد سيد</li>
 </ul>

</fieldset>
```

i retrieve this htmltext in variable in c#
ok then i have div in my aspx

```
 <div id="ulAndil" runat="server" ></div>
```

i want to render these html in div and loop through these controls like ul an il
all this in one method at run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it fastly through this way.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append("<fieldset>\n");
str.Append("<ul id=\"ContentPlaceHolder2_1g\" class=\"profList column ui-sortable\">\n");
str.Append("<legend class=\"group\">المجموعه 1</legend>\n");
str.Append("<li id=\"ContentPlaceHolder2_8\">محمود حسن ابراهيم عبد الصمد</li>\n");
str.Append("</ul></fieldset>\n");
str.Append("<fieldset>\n");
str.Append("<ul id=\"ContentPlaceHolder2_2g\" class=\"profList column ui-sortable\">\n");
str.Append("<legend class=\"group\">المجموعه 2</legend>\n");
str.Append("<li id=\"ContentPlaceHolder2_9\">محمود فتحى ابراهيم عبد الصمد</li>\n");
str.Append("<li id=\"ContentPlaceHolder2_10\">احمد محسن احمد على</li>");
str.Append("<li class=\"\" style=\"\" id=\"ContentPlaceHolder2_3\">احمد درويش محمود عباس</li>\n");
str.Append("</ul>\n");
str.Append("</fieldset>\n");
str.Append("<fieldset>\n");
str.Append("<ul id=\"ContentPlaceHolder2_3g\" class=\"profList column ui-sortable\">\n");
str.Append("<legend class=\"group\">المجموعه 3</legend>\n");
str.Append("<li id=\"ContentPlaceHolder2_11\">محمد سيد محمد سيد</li>\n");
str.Append("</ul>\n");
str.Append("</fieldset>\n");

ulAndil.InnerHtml = str.ToString();
```

Comment: thank u for replay but at run time this inner html change dynamicaly ul and il an fieldlist increase or decrease  and another thig when i loop in div control as '
      foreach (HtmlGenericControl item in ulAndil.Controls)
'   no ul or il in ulAndil.Controls why idonnot know although in depug ulAndil.innerhtml contain all text i passed

Comment: its example you will make it dynamic by creating loop etc, making value of attribute id, text etc dynamic, store dynamic data in stringbuilder and at the end pass it to div.

Comment: i want to take the hole text and store in div and render controls to loop in these controls